# Python set variable in switch statement

Tags: python, switch-statement, getter-setter

i try to set variables dependend on the type with an switch case statement.

I have a class *rule* with looks as following:

```
class rule:

    def __init__(self):
        name = ""
        src = ""

    def setName(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name
    name = property(getName, setName)

    def setSrc(self, src):
        self.__src = src

    def getSrc(self):
        return self.__src
    src = property(getSrc, setSrc)
```

and a text file as following

```
option <type> <value>
option name myname
option src anysrc
```

I search for the string **option** and get the secound and third string. as far as good. 
e.g. (qick and dirty):

```
with open("file") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.find('option') != -1:
            type(line.split(' ')[1], line.split(' ')[2])
```

Now I have write a switch case statement to set variable in object *rule*.

```
def type(option, value):
    switcher = {
        "name": rule.name = value,
        "src": rule.src = value,
    }
    switcher.get(option, lambda: "Invalid Option")
```

But this will not work, I face following:

```
  File "./read.py", line 112
    "name": rule.name = value,
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue or how to solve this by an other way.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: There is no switch statement in Python. You are trying to use a syntax that does not exist. If you want to use a dictionary for control flow like this, you need to write lambda functions, not statements, inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: Your concrete example you could use `setattr` You'd just have to check separately whether option is in the set of allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

Python has no switch statement. The common replacement - as you already seem to know - is using a dictionary to dispatch different behaviors. With that being the case however, the syntax you're trying to use simply isn't allowed for dictionaries. Dictionary key values should be *expressions*. You can work around this by using anonymous functions and `setattr`. Here's a self-contained example:

```
>>> class Dummy:
        pass

>>> dummy = Dummy()
>>> dic = {
    'a': lambda: setattr(dummy, 'a', 0),
    'b': lambda: setattr(dummy, 'b', 0)
}
>>> dic.get('a', lambda: print("Invalid Option"))()
>>> dummy.a
0
>>> dic.get('b', lambda: print("Invalid Option"))()
>>> dummy.b
0
>>> dic.get('x', lambda: print("Invalid Option"))()
Invalid Option
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are actually not defining a switch statement up there:

```
switcher = {
    "name": rule.name = value,
    "src": rule.src = value,
}
```

This is a dictionary, and the interpreter is complaining about the statements as value there.

You could just reference your methods like this:

```
def type(option, value):
    switcher = {
        "name": rule.setName,
        "src": rule.setSrc
    } 

    method = switcher.get(option, lambda: "Invalid Option")
    method(rule, value)
```

**Another idea**

Here is another aproach. Maybe something like this is helpful:

```
def type(rule, option, value):
    if hasattr(rule, option):
        setattr(rule, option, value)
    else:
        print("Invalid Option") # Some error handling
```

**Explicitly checking the option name**

@PaulPanzer pointed out, that it is maybe in your intention to explicitly check weather options are correct. So here is a more secure version of the `type`function:

```
def type(rule, option, value):
    if option in ["name", "src"]:
        setattr(rule, option, value)
    else:
        print("Invalid Option") # Some error handling
```

This implies that you have to change the code in two different places, whenever you extend your file format. But this is a question of how defensive you want to be, how often the rules get extended and how much flexibility you need.

Comment: `hasattr(rule)`?

Comment: You're missing a second argument for `hasattr`.

Comment: Correct. Edited that. Thx.

Comment: Syntax aside I wouldn't use `hasattr` here since it is unlikely that you want all attributes settable this way. Why not check against a set with the expected options?

Comment: Ah. Good one. If I get this correctly, you mean to check for "setSrc" rather than "src"?

Comment: No, I meant `if option in {'src', 'name'}: ... else: raise ...` Because there is no reason to assume that `rule` wouldn't have other attributes that shouldn't be exposed by this function.

Comment: Okay. Gotcha. It implies that you have to change the code in two different places when you want to extend your file format. But I think that is a little bit a question of how defensive you want to be. How often the rules get extended and how much flexibility you need.